# Given time intervals, find the minimum number of conference rooms required

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge

**The task** is taken from LeetCode

> *Given an array of meeting time intervals consisting of start and end times [[s1,e1],[s2,e2],...] (si < ei), find the minimum number of
>   conference rooms required.*
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: [[0, 30],[5, 10],[15, 20]]
> Output: 2
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: [[7,10],[2,4]]
> Output: 1
> ```
>
> **NOTE:** *input types have been changed on April 15, 2019. Please reset to default code definition to get new method signature.*

**My solution**

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} intervals
 * @return {number}
 */
var minMeetingRooms = function(intervals) {
  if (intervals.length <= 1) { return intervals.length; }

  const startTimes = [];
  const endTimes = [];
  intervals.forEach(x => {
    startTimes.push(x[0]);
    endTimes.push(x[1]);
  });
  startTimes.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  endTimes.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  let startPointer = 0;
  let endPointer = 0;
  let rooms = 0;
  while(startPointer < intervals.length) {
    if (startTimes[startPointer++] >= endTimes[endPointer]) {
      ++endPointer;
    } else {
      ++rooms    
    }
  }
  return rooms;
};
```

Comment: Can downvoters please explain the reason why they downvoted this question?

Comment: I personally did not downvote but I'd recommend taking a look at [Simon's Guide to posting a good question](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429). You could improve by providing a description of the approach you are using, for example. Also, why is this called "Meeting Rooms II"? Is it a follow-up to a previous question?

Comment: Also, your link leads to Leetcode Premium. I mean, not everyone will have a premium account on Leetcode (such as myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks much simpler than I would expect for this task. I tried several examples but could neither make it fail, nor did I understand why and how this algorithm works, I was only delighted that it seems to work. Therefore I have only a few remarks.

The early return for `length <= 1` is not necessary.

The `++rooms` is missing the semicolon.

Apart from that, it looks perfect.

Comment: Whenever a meeting finishes, no new room is required for the next start. Whenever a meeting starts while a meeting is in progress, a new room is required. A meeting is in progress when _startTimes[startPointer] < endTimes[endPointer]_. The neat trick is that _endPointer_ gets incremented conditionally and that the algorithm does not care about a meeting as start-end, but looks at all meetings as a set of starts and ends.

Comment: You sort the `startTime` and `endTime`. Then you iterate through every `startTime` and compare it with the current smallest `endTime`. If there is a `startTime` that is less than the current `endTime`, then you know there is a meeting still going on. Therefore you need a room. If the `startTime` is equal or greater than the `endTime`, then you know a meeting has ended and is free and you can use that free room for your current meeting. Therefore no new room is need, instead you look at the next `endTime` (i.e. increment the `endPointer`). And so on. You do this until all meetings are checked.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in C++ could use a min heap to store the end times.
This will help clean the code as you could achieve implicit sorting by using min heap.

```
int solve(vector<vector<int> > &A) {
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int>> pq;
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    for(auto& i : A){
        pq.push(i[1]);
    }
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < A.size() ; ++i){
        if(!pq.empty() && A[i][0] >= pq.top())
            pq.pop();
        else
            ++ans;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, you could improve your answer by explaining why adding a min heap improves the solution. Code only answers can be down voted and deleted by the community.

Comment: @RolandIllig This is true. I added the language.